# Is there a way to turn on type sharing between two Axis2 stubs generated using wsdl2java?

Tags: web-services, wsdl, apache-axis, wsdl2java

We have Axis2 POJO services that are currently consumed by a C# client and we're adding a Java client.  Generating equivalent stubs is turning out to be somewhat difficult.

We generate the classes using the .NET wsdl tool which has an option to share types between multiple services.

```
http://mymachine/appname/services/Service1?wsdl
http://mymachine/appname/services/Service2?wsdl
...ect
```

For the C# client we use the wsdl tool included with Visual Studio and life is wonderful

```
wsdl /n:MyPackage /out:ourservice-webservice.cs /sharetypes "http://mymachine/appname/services/Service1?wsdl" "http://mymachine/appname/services/Service2?wsdl"
```

Now we're trying to add a Java client and I'm running into an issue using the code generated from wsdl2java

```
wsdl2java -uri http://mymachine/appname/services/Service1?wsdl -uw -or -o src -p MyPackage  
wsdl2java -uri http://mymachine/appname/services/Service2?wsdl -uw -or -o src -p MyPackage
```

This seemed to work until I tried to use a call from Service1 and one from Service2 that both use the type MyTransaction.

Right now the generated stubs show it as Service1Stub.MyTransaction and Service2Stub.MyTransaction which are of course different types.

This is a problem as we have to move objects back and forth across the two services.  I assume there's an easy fix I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've noted, the databinding classes (`MyTransaction` and so on) are being generated as inner classes of the stub classes. So each stub has its own copy of the `MyTransaction` class which isn't compatible with the other one.

The *wsdl2java* parameter `-u` will cause the databinding classes to be generated as regular classes, each in its own file. If the two `MyTransaction` definitions are actually identical, then *wsdl2java* would generate the same class file for each of the `MyTransaction` objects, and you'd be able to share `MyTransaction` objects between the two services.

[This page](http://wso2.com/library/tutorials/reference-guide-axis2-code-generation-parameters-part-1/) describes the *wsdl2java* parameters in detail.